# Under COPPA, if a person says their age on a site and apparently were younger than 13 when they joined, does the site have to do anything?

Tags: internet, coppa

If a user on a website with a 13+ age rule as required by The Children's Online Privacy Protection Act, such as Stack Exchange, signs up in year 1, then says in year 3 that they are less than 15 (and thus were less than 13 when they signed up), **does the company running the site legally have to do anything, such as deleting the data from before they were 13?**

<sub>I know that this law is de facto almost powerless; I'm just curious about how it's **supposed** to work.</sub>